# Are any magical acts ever claimed on behalf of The Seven?

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire, game-of-thrones

Even though the texts of The Song of Ice and Fire series do not confirm whether or not the various gods exist, there are certainly many magical acts claimed on their behalf by their adherents. The gods of Essos very clearly have acts claimed by their adherents, and the Old Gods are seen as active in the north (though I'm not sure if it's explicitly stated that they are responsible for the skinchangers.)

Does the series ever present any magical acts as being caused by The Seven?

And though the Ironborn gods are nowhere near as prominent, the same can be asked for them: are any magical acts claimed to be their work?

Comment: You should take a look at [this question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/43463/2256), answers and comments.

Comment: @Mooz Related but not identical. If anything this is the broader question. The gods could have powers without the septons/septas having any.

Comment: This is not a duplicate. Things which have been brought up below include answering prayer and the results of trial by combat. It also asks about the Drowned God.

Comment: If you want to know about the Drowned God, ask another question.

Comment: @WOPR That would be fair enough. This question is still broader than the on it has been marked a duplicate of.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, up to this point in the series there are no magical acts that are attributed to The Seven.

We never see any magic from the Drowned God either, although Aeron Greyjoy credits the god with saving each of the men that he has drowned as part of their initiation into the faith:

> *Another one returned.* It was a sign of the Drowned God's favor, men said. Every other priest lost a man from time to time ... But never Aeron Greyjoy. He was the Damphair, who had seen the god's own watery halls and returned to tell of it.

Comment: So are the Lord of Light and the Many-Faced God the only gods that have been "confirmed," so to say?

Comment: None of the gods have been confirmed, except perhaps the old gods based on what has happened in the show. There are several types of magic however.

Answer (score 3):

There are several mentions to septons who are able to heal people and cure the blind. In addition to that, people seem to attribute events to the Seven based on their prayer, although that may not truly count as magic. Also during trials of Combat, the Seven are expected to aid the side of truth. Swords suddenly snapping or armor failing at a critical moment are attributed to the Seven intervening. Not true magic, but still a 'supernatural' event if pure luck is discounted.

As for the Ironborn, there are some things that could be said about their gods. Supposedly the storm god conjured the winds that killed Balon Greyjoy, although that may very well be only guessing on Aeron's part. However, Aeron clearly has some sort of super-human thing going on: He drinks pretty much exclusively salt seawater, which may be something he can do because of his belief in the Drowned God.

Comment: If I recall correctly, there was speculation that Balon was actually assassinated, presumably by someone working for Euron, so I'm not sure if the "Storm God's winds" are valid, but overall an excellent answer, especially the catch about Aeron drinking seawater.